# JavaScript equivalent to C strncmp (compare string for length)

Tags: javascript, string, string-matching

Is there an equivalent in JavaScript to the C function `strncmp`?  `strncmp` takes two string arguments and an integer `length` argument.  It would compare the two strings for up to `length` chars and determine if they were equal as far as `length` went.

Does JavaScript have an equivalent built in function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could easily build that function:

```
function strncmp(str1, str2, n) {
  str1 = str1.substring(0, n);
  str2 = str2.substring(0, n);
  return ( ( str1 == str2 ) ? 0 :
                              (( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ));
}
```

An alternative to the ternary at the end of the function could be the [`localeCompare`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.9) method e.g `return str1.localeCompare(str2);`

Comment: I built it a little differently, but thanks.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel first.

Comment: actually it's not equivalent (it only returns 0, -1 or 1, the c-Function returns more values), but I think it's enough for most cases

Comment: Shouldn't you use === ?

Answer (score 3):

It does not. You could define one as:

```
function strncmp(a, b, n){
    return a.substring(0, n) == b.substring(0, n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since ECMAScript 2015 there is [`startsWith()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.startswith):

```
str.startsWith(searchString[, position])
```

This covers the very frequent use case where the length of the comparison is the length of the `searchString`, and only a boolean return value is required (`strcmp()` returns an integer to indicate relative order, instead.)

The [Mozilla doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) also contains a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) for `String.prototype.startsWith()`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't but you can find one [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/strncmp:543), along with [many other useful javascript functions](http://phpjs.org/functions/index).

```
function strncmp ( str1, str2, lgth ) {
    // Binary safe string comparison  
    // 
    // version: 909.322
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strncmp
    // +      original by: Waldo Malqui Silva
    // +         input by: Steve Hilder
    // +      improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +       revised by: gorthaur
    // + reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // *     example 1: strncmp('aaa', 'aab', 2);
    // *     returns 1: 0
    // *     example 2: strncmp('aaa', 'aab', 3 );
    // *     returns 2: -1
    var s1 = (str1+'').substr(0, lgth);
    var s2 = (str2+'').substr(0, lgth);

    return ( ( s1 == s2 ) ? 0 : ( ( s1 > s2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
}
```

Comment: `substring` is faster than `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

you could always [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) the strings first, and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
function strncmp(a, b, length) {
   a = a.substring(0, length);
   b = b.substring(0, length);

   return a == b;
}
```